Debian 12 won't accept remote ssh connections
I'm trying to set up a Debian 12 server, and I can't get it to accept ssh connections from my Ubuntu 22.04 machine (or an older Ubuntu machine). It doesn't ask for a password; the ssh command just terminates immediately. Ssh to localhost and [Debian 12 IP] both work - prompts for password, accepts it, and logs in. This should be a close-to-stock install of Debian 12. I even tried copying the stock sshd_config file from the Ubuntu 22.04 machine (which accepts connections from the Debian machine) to the Debian machine, but no success.
Here's what the Ubuntu 22.04 machine gives when I attempt a connection:
[localuser]@[localmachine]:~$ ssh -vvv [remoteuser]@192.168.2.9
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.2.9 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/[localuser]/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/[localuser]/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.9 [192.168.2.9] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 192.168.2.9 port 22
[localuser]@[localmachine]:~$ 

This is what the Debian machine reports:
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[5704]: debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[5704]: debug1: Forked child 8037.
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[5704]: debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 3271
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[5704]: debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[5704]: debug3: send_rexec_state: done
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[8037]: debug3: oom_adjust_restore
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[8037]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[8037]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[8037]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[8037]: debug1: getpeername failed: Transport endpoint is not connected
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[8037]: debug3: process_channel_timeouts: setting 0 timeouts
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[8037]: debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
Dec 06 21:45:08 fafnir sshd[8037]: debug1: ssh_remote_port failed

The config file is currently:

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO
LogLevel Debug3

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Any idea what's going wrong? Note I haven't installed or configured any firewall software, but it's possible there's something stock I'm not aware of.

Have you considered updating the client software? Your openssh-client seems to be rather dated... the current version in Jammy is OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.15 3 Sep 2024

Another thing to try is to spawn an sshd on the far end on a different port w/ debugging set and trying to connect to that.

All of the keys your ssh tried to load (identity file /home/[localuser]/.ssh/id_rsa) failed (-1). Have you run ssh-keygen followed by `ssh copy id?

Debian doesn't allow root-login for SSH in default.

According to the error, the client is making a TCP connection to the server, then the connection is closing immediately, before any kind of ssh protocol negotiation can start. See if there's a firewall running on the server that might be interfering with connections to port 22.

Tink: Apt (on Ubuntu 22.04) apparently doesn't have a newer version of openssh-client; it reports that I already have the newest version (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.10).
Waltinator: I'm trying to use password authentication rather than keys. Does the fact that there are no local keys cause problems?
Paladin: I'm not trying to log in as root, so that setting shouldn't be relevant.
Kenster: "ufw status", "iptables", and "sestatus" all report "command not found", while "nft list ruleset" gives no output. (All run as root.)

The really bizarre thing is, I changed LogLevel to Debug3 and restarted sshd to get better logs - and it connected. Can't figure out what was changed. But now it's rejecting connections again; it's been only 10 minutes or so, and the only thing I've changed was the greeter.dconf-defaults file to prevent it from going to sleep (but haven't restarted gdm3).

Just now, ssh wouldn't connect - until I pinged the Debian machine from the Ubuntu one at the same time as trying to ssh, then it connected fine. What in the world is going on???

Do you have two machines that use the same IP on that subnet/reachable from your workstation?

No, definitely just the one. And the ping behavior is consistent - if I don't ping the server first, I get the "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" message as above (regardless of number of attempts), but if I ping it and then attempt ssh, it connects just fine. The ping does not have to be running during the ssh attempt; a couple seconds beforehand works. A few minutes later, it rejects ssh connections again. (Note: I updated the question's codeblocks a couple of days ago, after adding Debug3 on sshd.)

What's the firewalling like on either end, do you go through any firewalls along the way?

To the best of my knowledge, no; I haven't intentionally set up a firewall on either end or in between, and it's just the Ubuntu machine connecting to the router via wifi (wrote everything on this question via that machine, so no issues there), with the Debian server connected to the same router via ethernet. Firewall is turned off on the router. I also tried starting a second sshd on port 23 - exactly the same behavior, needed to ping the machine before it connected via ssh.

Can you please check both iptables -L -n -v and iptables -L -n -v (not that v6 should be an issue as you're using v4 addresses, not names) and paste the output into your question? And given the fact that it's all local ... I'm starting to suspect your router; I've never in my close to 30 years of using Linux seen ssh do that, and I've seen weird things  :D ...

Found it! The Debian machine's subnet mask was set to 255.255.255.255 (CIDR 192.168.2.9/32), making it think it was the only machine on the subnet. Check the CIDR with "ip addr". Changing subnet to 255.255.255.0 (CIDR 192.168.2.9/24, like it should have been) fixed ssh. How ping would get ssh to work, I still don't know, but it was a usable workaround.
How I missed this in my first several rounds of DDG searches, I don't know either. But here's things to try (in addition to subnet) for anyone else who has this problem:
18.04 - Unable to SSH into server until I've pinged it - Ask Ubuntu
ssh - Ubuntu server can be accessed only after ping - Server Fault
SSH connection to my home server ONLY works if server is pinging back at the same time : r/linux4noobs (reddit.com)
[SOLVED] ssh can't connect, then I ping, then ssh can, how can it be ? weird situation... (linuxquestions.org)
